# Display loading icon during Page.Redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to have some sort of Loading Icon to appear between pages of my web form. Some of the pages take a while to load due to calls to web services.

I am trying to implement a loading spinner during these page redirects till the page is ready.

I have tried to achieve this with a simple:

```
Jquery
$(window).load(function () {
    $('#LoadingPanel').fadeOut(2000);
})

html
<div id="LoadingPanel" style="background-image: url(Images/loading_spinner.gif); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 100px 100px; height: 100px; width: 100px; position: fixed; z-index: 1000; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin: -25px 0 0 -25px">
</div>
```

The only problem with this is that is doesn't actually appear till a minute into the page load.

Is what I am trying to achieve possible? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

*UPDATE*

Page1 : On the first page the user fills out a form and then hits a button which will save the user entry and then redirect to another page.

```
Protected Sub Btn_BestBuy_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Btn_BestBuy.ServerClick

    StoreDetails(sender, e)
    Response.Redirect("Plugin.aspx?step=4&results=best&stdid=" & STDID.Value & "&stid=" & STID.Value & IIf(Session("sid") <> "", "&sid=" & Session("sid"), ""))

End Sub
```

StoreDetails() Saves the user entries to a array and then moves the array to a session:

```
Application("DETAILS_ARRAY") = DetailsArray
```

Page2: One the second page the page does a web service call using the details entered in the first page:

```
If Request.QueryString("results") = "best" Then

    GetSchemes(Service.PublicBestType.ALL)

End If
```

GetSchemes calls the web-service and returns all the data into a session which is bound to a grid-view at the bottom of the page load.

What it looks like is happening is when the page starts to bind the data to the grids the Loading icon appears.

Comment: Have you try $(document).ready(function(){})

Comment: I have, It does the same thing essentially. The loading icon doesn't show up early enough but does go away at the right time.

Comment: Your method seems good. your div is at the beginning of your page ?

Comment: Yeah, It's the first thing in the body of the page.

Comment: Okay. Try to add your css in a file maybe it will be faster.

Comment: Just gave that a go and still it doesn't appear when it should. Let me give a bit more detail. I have the loading Icon on two pages. I have a button that runs a function and redirects to the other page. The icon should appear when the button is clicked. It should remain visible during the page redirect and finally go hidden once the second page is ready.

Comment: Can you share the code of the first page ?

Comment: Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

As you write in your comment

> The icon should appear when the button is clicked. It should remain visible during the page redirect and finally go hidden once the second page is ready.

You load a complete new Page after finishing your webservice call?

Why you don't give your loadingPanel "display:none" and show the loading div in your button-click event?

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#yourBtn", function(event) {
    jQuery("#LoadingPanel").show();
    //your webservice call
});
```

And when the second page finally is loaded, the LoadingPanel is in it basic status --> display: none;

Comment: The Web service call is done during the initial page load of the second page and is done via the code behind, It is returning a few thousand records so it takes a while. When the button is clicked It saves the Items in the web-form via a simple function and then begins the page.redirect to the second page.

Comment: Okay, i have misunderstood this scenario. 
Could you write a little more of your code? Maybe there is some small failure which I can't see now.

Maybe it is possible to do a workaround over AJAX?
So you load your second page, show the loading-screen and then call your webservice over ajax, and after the ajax call, you disable the loading screen